# SQL Deleting from a join table not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

The below is returning a syntax error issue.
Having searched thoroughly online, I cannot see why. Any ideas?

```
delete Tracks                                                                                                                                                     
from tracks                                                                                                                                                                      
left join releases                                                                                                                                                               
on tracks.label_id=releases.label_id                                                                                                                                             
where tracks.label_id = 185 
and releases.id = 4394 
and tracks.position = 1 
and tracks.name != 'Da Antidote';
```

The Syntax error is on line 1.

Comment: what the error says ? can you show the whole error message ?

Comment: Could be a case sensitive matter. Have you tried `delete tracks                                                                                                                                                     
from tracks ...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly Postgres doesn't allow joins in `DELETE`, but you can use the `USING`keyword instead like [described in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html):

```
DELETE FROM Tracks 
USING releases  
WHERE tracks.label_id=releases.label_id  
AND tracks.label_id = 185 
AND releases.id = 4394 
AND tracks.position = 1 
AND tracks.name != 'Da Antidote';
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks jpw. I will be sure to consult the documentation before asking in the future. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from tracks                                                                                                                                                                      
left join releases                                                                                                                                                               
on tracks.label_id=releases.label_id                                                                                                                                             
where tracks.label_id = 185 
and releases.id = 4394 
and tracks.position = 1 
and tracks.name != 'Da Antidote';
```

Comment: This doesn't work as you can't use joins in delete with Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an EXISTS clause:

```
DELETE FROM tracks t1 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM releases t2 WHERE 
        t1.label_id = t2.label_id
        AND yadda, yadda, yadda
);
```